# Issue with Fractional Knapsack

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my implemented code in Java. The **getmax()** function returns the index of the maximum element.The issue is, I am not getting one of my test cases correct. I don't know which one, but online judge is giving me following warning:

> Failed case #7/13: Wrong answer
>   got: 66152.57 expected: 66152.572
>    (Time used: 0.19/1.50, memory used: 24469504/671088640.)

```
public class FractionalKnapsack {
private static double getOptimalValue(int capacity, int[] values, int[] weights) {
    float value = 0;
    //write your code here
    float[] ratio=new float[values.length];
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
    {
        ratio[i]=(float)values[i]/(float)weights[i];
    }
    int max=0;

    while(capacity>-1)
    {
        max=getMax(ratio);
        if(capacity==0)
        {
            return value;
        }
        if(capacity>0)
        {
            if(weights[max]>=capacity)
            {
                value=value+((float)ratio[max]*(float)(capacity));
                capacity=0;
            }
            else if(capacity>weights[max])
            {
                value=value+(weights[max]*ratio[max]);
                capacity=capacity-weights[max];
            }
            ratio[max]=0;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
private static int getMax(float[] arr)
{
    float max=0;
    int save=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>max)
        {
            max=arr[i];
            save=i;
        }
    }
    return save;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int capacity = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] values = new int[n];
    int[] weights = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        weights[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.applyPattern(".0000");
    System.out.println(df.format(getOptimalValue(capacity, values, weights)));
}
```

}

Comment: your answer is off by .002 so it must just be some simple rounding error or formatting in your print

Comment: That's a very close answer. Just a guess, but have you tried using doubles?

Answer (score 1):

The `float` type you use can not distinguish between 66152.57 (your output) and 66152.572 (desired output). You may check it [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) online, for example. See, the mantissa has only 23 bits of storage which means that relative error can well be on the order of 2<sup>-24</sup>. For magnitude 66152.572, it means the absolute error of 0.003943. If you become further interested in the why, look up some floating point guide (like [this one](http://floating-point-gui.de/)).

The solution is to use `double` for floating-point calculations.
Note that, unless you actually know `float` precision is enough for your application, `double` is almost always the right type to use to avoid such unfortunate effects.